# Visual Studio 2010 Architecture tooling

Tags: architecture, visual-studio-2010

Has anyone played around with the architecture tools (uml diagrams, etc) in VS 2010 and if so what is your opinion?  I really am liking Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect but am also curious about what is available in VS 2010.  I'm not looking for responses about how much you hate Microsoft tools or love mircosoft tools, but more for answers about how useful VS2010 arc tools are for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS 2010 architecture tools appear useful in it's current state, but I think EA provides more features for the entire SDLC management.

I would really like to have one integrated solution for building architecture all the way down to engineering the code.  As I use VS 2010, it would be great if all of the features of EA were in VS 2010.  I just feel like VS 2010 architecture tools are lacking.  And EA provides lots of features for tracking individual model objects all the way to resource management and dynamic reporting capabilities for different audiences.

One thing I'm not sure VS 2010 supports traceability which is a valuable tool in EA.  Another thing I notice that is missing is a way to gather requirements.  VS 2010 starts with the Use Case modelling.  I think the integration of requirements gathering is valuable to maintain in the same diagrams/models.

Answer (score 1):

The layer diagrams with their dependency validation are very useful.

The **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Downloads&referringTitle=Home)** shows how this works. Please download the .NET4 version.